# R opening a specific worksheet in a excel workbook using shell.exec

Tags: r

I can open an excel workbook from within R using:

```
 shell.exec("abc.xlsx")
```

but how can I open the workbook at a specific worksheet using shell exec?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Not from R (at not least via `shell.exec()`) but you *can* do it by adding a macro to the `abc.xlsx` file: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/22113-how-open-workbook-specific-sheet-everytime.html. There are no command-line switches that you can add on to the `exec` call to point to a specific worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not use `shell.exec` but does open the specified sheet:

```
# start Excel
library(RDCOMClient)
xl <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xl[["Visible"]] <- TRUE

# activate second sheet of indicated xlsx file
file <- normalizePath("abc.xlsx")
sheetNo <- 2  
xl[["Workbooks"]]$Open(file)$Sheets(sheetNo)$Activate()
```

To specify sheet name instead of number replace last two lines with:

```
sheetName <- "Sheet2"
xl[["Workbooks"]]$Open(file)$Sheets(sheetName)$Activate()
```